# How to run postgres in-memory on windows and sync to FS when a temer runs out?

Tags: postgresql, optimization, windows, snapshot, in-memory-database

So Progress is slow for me (in terms of query and update times) on SSD and it is ok in my case: I use it as a mix of Graph database + Table processor + NoSQL JSON trees so lots of loops, graphs, trees,...  Yet my data is not so large - it all can fit into RAM 3 times. So I want to speed Postgres up - have it all run in RAM and sync to SSD/HDD once in N minutes. In my dream world, it would save\update only the diff between the current snapshot and the previous one. Is it possible to configure Postgres to do such a thing?

Answer (score 3):

That's how PostgreSQL operates by default – just set `shared_buffers` so that the whole database fits in it.

Inefficient queries can be slow even on a small database that is cached in memory. You will have to tune your workload.